# PhpmyAdmin user name and password for WIMP Server

Tags: phpmyadmin, webserver

I am installing WIMP Server to machine using wimpserver2.2.exe. After installing the files are copied into Webserver (IIS) when i browse PHP files It is asking username and password to enter into account.

When i use the username as root and password for blank. It will shows the error like 'Access denied' and  'root@localhost' is username and password='YES'

Please tell the default username and password for phpmyAdmin account.

Thanks in advance.

Naresh.

Comment: What did you set up for mysql? It's same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.cyberls.com/forum/Thread-How-To-Reset-MySQL-Admin-Password-In-Wndows-server) link helps you to change the root password.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html) is an another link from mysql page .

Password for root on phpmyadmin site is same as you can use with the mysql database.

Comment: Thank you, I did it. I am creating new users and Grant privileges to new users with root priviligies